# Test function with default non-constant arguments

Tags: kotlin, testing, mocking

I have a method which works with time and therefore I need to pass current time to it as an argument in order to make it testable:

```
fun dummy(now: Instant = Instant()) = true
```

However, I cannot mock it with `Mockito`, I think because in the code it is called without the default argument. `classA.dummy()` always returns `false`. I cannot use `dummy(any())` because Mockito complains it is null. How to test this kind of functions?

```
@Test
fun test() {
    whenever(classA.dummy()).thenReturn(true)

    classUnderTest.execute()

    verify(classB).execute()
}

class ClassUnderTest {

    @Inject lateinit var classA: ClassA
    @Inject lateinit var classB: ClassB

    fun execute() {
       if (classA.dummy()) classB.execute()
    }

 }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because the default parameter is an instant so in `whenever` is instant 1,  but then when is executed is instant 2, it could be a milliseconds difference or it could be the reference is not the same; the argumenta doesn't match. You have to pass the instant to `execute`

```
val instant = Instant()
whenever(classA.dummy(instant)).thenReturn(true)

classUnderTest.execute(instant)
//...
```

And the class under test

```
fun execute(instant: Intant = Instant) {
       if (classA.dummy(instant)) classB.execute()
}
```

Comment: Thank for reply. Is there a better way to handle time? I want to avoid passing one same parameter through many method calls. You can imagine `execute` can have several nested method which in the end call `dummy`

Comment: Sadly I have found this problem myself when working with `DateTime` or similar and seems to be the same problem, you could default it to the second stripping of the millis and that could work unless the time class you are using doesn't apply structural equivalent and can only be compared by reference. Another way could be `whenever` using `any()` so that should work but is a non-deterministic test.

Answer (score 0):

There is a utility function in Joda library, which sets the current time and there is not need to pass time as an argument. See [setCurrentMillisFixed](https://www.joda.org/joda-time/apidocs/org/joda/time/DateTimeUtils.html#setCurrentMillisFixed-long-)

For example:

```
import org.joda.time.DateTimeUtils

@Before
fun setUp() {
    DateTimeUtils.setCurrentMillisFixed(DateTime(2020, 11, 5, 10, 0, 0).millis)
}

@After
fun cleanup() {
    DateTimeUtils.setCurrentMillisSystem()
}
```